# Can I send a notification in the creation and deletion of an entity?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I want to be notified when an entity is created or deleted.
Does Orion support subscribing to the creation and deletion of entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, in Orion Context Broker - NGSIv2 - you have got the following alteration triggers:

**entityUpdate**: notification is sent whenever a entity covered by the subscription is updated (no matter if the entity actually changed or not)

**entityChange**: notification is sent whenever a entity covered by the subscription is updated and it actually changes (or if it is not an actual update, but forcedUpdate option is used in the update request)

**entityCreate**: notification is sent whenever a entity covered by the subscription is created

**entityDelete**: notification is sent whenever a entity covered by the subscription is deleted

Complete documentation:
https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#subscriptions-based-in-alteration-type

Best.